# DRF - Add/Exclude fields based on instance's field values

Tags: django-rest-framework

I have a model named `Notification` which has a field named `notification_type`. Now in `NotificationSerializer.__init__`, I want to check the value of the `notification_type` field of the model instance and based on it's value, I want to add / remove some fields on the serializer. Is that possible?

I have tried `self.instance` inside the `__init__` method but in case of the `many=True`, it's a queryset. I want to modify based on each model instance. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible, but not on the serializer's `__init__`. Use the serializer's `to_representation` method instead.

```
def to_representation(self, obj):
    data = super().to_representation(obj)
    # data is your serialized instance

    if obj.notification_type == 'type1':
        data.pop('attr2')
    elif obj.notification_type == 'type2':
        data.pop('attr1')

    return data
```